# Providing @Input data to ion-tabs ( Ionic 3.5.3 )

Tags: lazy-loading, ionic3

I'm on ionic 3.5.3 and I'm wondering if I've missed something in the ion-tab specs.

I know you can provide data via rootParams to the navController of the target state but as I'm lazy-loading components I wanted to provide data that would be bound to @Input on the target component thus allowing it to be any comoponent. Is this not possible?

For example I can use the component within other pages like this

> `<my-component [boundData]="boundData"></my-component>`

but I would also like to navigate to the component directly in an ion-tab using

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [tabUrlPath]="mycomponent" [root]="'my-component'" [boundData]="boundData" 
  </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

This doesn't work as boundData is not recognized as a template input for ion-tab. I'm wondering if I've missed some way of providing a set of @inputs?

Comment: So have you declared boundData as an attribute directive?

Comment: There is rootParams as well - would that not give you what you want with your 'boundData'?

Comment: boundData is an [at]input. rootParams are fed in as navParams so the components would need to inject NavParams in the constructor and extract what is needed from there which seems to preclude using [at]Input and [at]Output